# PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am using WildFly 10, Java EE, JPA, and Hibernate. Recently I migrated my application from MySQL to PostgreSQL. While using MySQL, I would store images in my entities using:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] image;
```

This worked great, and MySQL used a `LONGBLOB` to store the data.

After switching to PostgreSQL, the column type is `OID`, and I receive this error when persisting the image:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:308)
at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.createLO(LargeObjectManager.java:296)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.createBlob(PgPreparedStatement.java:1202)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setBlob(PgPreparedStatement.java:1243)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setBlob(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:1157)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:112)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:252)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2598)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2883)
... 131 more
```

I am inserting in this way:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

...

//Simple insert method...
this.entityManager.persist(entity);
```

And this is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyApp" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                      value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have looked at multiple other questions regarding this exception, however I have been unable to solve the problem.

[One suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479964/2364405) was to create an entity solely for storing the data and use a `@OneToOne` relationship with it so that the entity storing data could be eagerly fetched, however this did not change the results in any way.

Another suggestion was to disable Hibernate's auto-commit with

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
```

...which also did nothing.

I am completely lost as to why this will not work. Seeming as how this does not appear to be a very common exception, I feel like I am approaching the task of storing image data in the completely wrong way. What can I do to fix this, or how should I be storing the data?

Comment: "I feel like I am approaching the task of storing image data in the completely wrong way." correct. Images should not be in the database at all

Comment: @e4c5 In my case, I don't see another option. This application will be scaled horizontally across multiple different WildFly installations. If I store the images on the local disk, it will not be accessible by all users. The only way I know how to combat this is by using the database. The images are no larger than 1MB each.

Comment: You don't have to store on local disk. You can store on S3, Google files or any number of CDNs. You will get a huge performance boost

Comment: "to create an entity solely for storing the data and use a @OneToOne relationship" that is a commonly suggested work around to get a form of "property" level lazy loading working in Hibernate. 
If you are using JPA you can try a different JPA implementation that supports lazy proper lazy loading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164072/large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot tell you how this is done in Hibernate, but opening and reading/writing a large object have to happen within the same database transaction.

Disabling autocommit mode should do the trick, maybe you did something wrong.

But may I suggest that you do not use large objects at all?
Usually it is much easier to use the `bytea` PostgreSQL data type, which can contain data up to 1GB of size. Unless you store and retrieve the data in chunks, large objects don't offer any advantage, and I doubt that you can fully exploit large object functionality with an ORM anyway.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the exception, it is currently the easiest alternative solution for me at the moment. Using `bytea` and removing the `@Lob` annotation is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it through a change in my JBOSS configuration file (standalone.xml or domain.xml).

Analysing the problem first I saw that auto commit was still true by logging

```
entityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).connection().getAutoCommit()
```

I tried setting it to false with

```
entityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).connection().setAutoCommit(false)
```

but this resulted in the exception "You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction".

Researching for the exception message I found [this article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/demystifying-datasource-jta-and-xa-settings-on-jboss-wildfly) that explains why auto commit was always true.

We were using a datasource configured like this:

```
<datasource jta="true"  . . . >
```

The problem is that in a JTA datasource the auto-commit setting is always true and it can not be changed. 
I changed it to an xa-datasource and the problem did not occur anymore.

```
<xa-datasource . . . .>
```

Also em.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).connection().getAutoCommit() finally returned false.

To make it work I also had to set the parameter max_prepared_transaction to 500 in postgres.conf in my Postgres database to allow multiple database connection/connection pooling:

```
max_prepared_transactions = 500     # zero disables the feature
```