# Hibernate with long text column with Oracle and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, oracle, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying make an entity work with Oracle (11.2) and PostgreSQL(9.4) in a Spring Boot (1.4.4) application.

My entity contains a long text field (over 4000 characters).
The appropriate data type in Oracle is CLOB and the corresponding type in PostgreSQL is TEXT.

I'm able to make it work with PostgreSQL

```
@Column(name = "LONG_TEXT", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String longText;
```

However it would fail with Oracle in hibernate validation stage since CLOB requires @Lob annotation.

The following code works with Oracle

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "LONG_TEXT")
private String longText;
```

However this time it fails when reading from PostgreSQL with the following exception:

> PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode

[Stack overflow suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164072/large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit-mode) performing queries in transactions. Disregarding questionable requirement to invoke transaction in select queries, adding @Transactional to query methods didn't help.

Any thoughts are more than welcomed.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution other than creating an identical entity that has the same `@Table` annotation but differs at the `@Lob`, but just to be clear: you have two persistence units sharing entity types or one app that uses different databases on different servers?

Comment: Did you try [`@Lob @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")`](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6105)? There was also a custom hibernate dialect workaround somewhere in SO.

Comment: @coladict - It's one app that needs to support two different databases.
Regarding creating different entities, is there a way doing that that would not result in changes in the entire code base?

Comment: @pozs - I did try it. No effect on Oracle and same exception in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Boris ah, you may need the `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType` as `StringClobType` may be deprecated (depends on your hibernate version).

Comment: `StringClobType` doesn't exist any more, so maybe try `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.ClobType")`. The PU builder chooses an override for Postgres when checking the dialect.

Comment: `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType` didn't as well. 
Will thy the `org.hibernate.type.ClobType`.

Comment: @coladict - `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.ClobType")` results in 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Clob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came to is to adopt the @Lob and @Transactional approach.

The main issue was with the placement of the @Transactional annotation, causing the PSQLException. Once fixed, we were able to work with both types of DBs.