# JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm writing a backend with Spring Boot and PostgreSQL. Basically i need to save images as base64 string in postgres and retrieve them. Response from POST method is ok, but when i try use GET spring throws this exception in the end of the image string:

`Could not write JSON: Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.mangaone.mangaone.domain.Manga[\\\"chapters\\\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->ru.mangaone.mangaone.domain.Chapter[\\\"pages\\\"])`

And this as root cause:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.`

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Manga {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String artist;
    private String year;
    private int views;
    private double rating;

    @Lob
    private String image;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Genre.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "manga_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<Genre> genres;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manga", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manga_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("chapters")
    private Manga manga;

    private int number;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Page.class, mappedBy = "chapter",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Page> pages;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Page {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("pages")
    private Chapter chapter;

    private int number;

    @Lob
    private String image;
}
```

**POST methods for chapter and page:**

```
@PostMapping()
    public Chapter createChapter(@RequestBody Manga manga) {
        List<Chapter> chapters = manga.getChapters();
        Chapter result = chapterRepository.save(chapters.get(chapters.size() - 1));
        mangaRepository.save(manga);

        return result;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/pages")
    public List<Page> createPages(@RequestBody List<Page> pages) {
        return pageRepository.saveAll(pages);
    }
```

**GET methods for manga:**

```
 @GetMapping
    public List<Manga> listManga() {
        return mangaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Manga getManga(@PathVariable("id") Manga manga) {
        return manga;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164072/large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit-mode)

Comment: By default LOBs are loaded lazy and that loading should happen in the same transaction as the parent objects are loaded.  Please check above link for the solution to this.

Comment: Yeah, that worked out but only with setting auto-commit false in application properties