# How to extract images (lob) from Postgresql in a Spring Boot app (Hibernate + JPA)?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a logic that takes images from f-end via byte[] in java, compress them and then store in Postgresql db in a column define with data lob.

Service:

```
 public CourseDto createNewCourse(CourseDto newCourseDto) throws SQLException {

    Courses course = courseRepositoryDao.findByCourseName(newCourseDto.getCourseName());
    if (course == null) {

        course = new Courses()
                .setCourseName(newCourseDto.getCourseName())
                .setCourseDescription(newCourseDto.getCourseDescription())
                .setCoursePrice(newCourseDto.getCoursePrice())
                .setIsCourseFree(newCourseDto.getIsCourseFree())
                .setIsCourseActive(newCourseDto.getIsCourseActive())
                .setLogo(compressZLib(newCourseDto.getLogo()));

        ;
        return CourseMapper.toUserDtoFreeCourses(courseRepositoryDao.save(course));
    }
    throw exception(EntityType.NEWCOURSE, ExceptionType.DUPLICATE_ENTITY, newCourseDto.getCourseName());
}

// compress the image bytes before storing it in the database
public static byte[] compressZLib(byte[] data) {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    deflater.finish();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("Compressed Image Byte Size - " + outputStream.toByteArray().length);

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I try to retrieve the images:

```
    public List<CourseDto> getCoureses() {

        List<Courses> courses = courseRepositoryDao.findAllByIsCourseFreeAndIsCourseActive(true, true);
        List<CourseDto> coursesNameDto = courses
                .stream()
                .peek(i -> i.setLogo(decompressZLib(i.getLogo())))
                .map(course -> modelMapper.map(CourseMapper.toUserDtoFreeCourses(course), CourseDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("**************************" + coursesNameDto + "**********************");
        return coursesNameDto;
    }
    // uncompress the image bytes before returning it to the angular application
    public static byte[] decompressZLib(byte[] data) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (!inflater.finished()) {
                int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

But I have this error: "Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode"

My entity class has this field on logo:

```
@Column(name = "picByte", length = 4000)
@Lob
private byte[] logo;
```

Comment: I'm able to recieve the object when using @Transactional on the service method, but it works only whenn ddl-auto is "create-drop". If I change the ddl-auto to "update" it dosent work with postman.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be duplicate of:
[Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164072/large-objects-may-not-be-used-in-auto-commit-mode)

Check it out if it solves your problem.

Comment: It dosen't solve it. I done the same with @Transactional, but it works only when I put ddl to "create-drop". When I put ddl to "update" my POSTMAN request is pending and wainting for response without returning anithing.